# Show reflection $s_\delta$ is given by multiplication with matrix $R_{\varphi_\delta}$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V = \mathbb R^2$ and $\langle , \rangle$ the standard symmetric bilinear form.

Find $\varphi_\delta \in [0, 2\pi)$ such that $s_\delta$ is given by multiplication with $\begin{pmatrix}\cos(\varphi_\delta) & \sin(\varphi_\delta) \\ \sin(\varphi_\delta) & - \cos(\varphi_\delta)\end{pmatrix}$.

We defined $s_\delta$ as $s_\delta:V \to V, v \mapsto v-2 \frac{\langle v, \delta \rangle}{\langle \delta, \delta \rangle}\delta$.

So I think $\varphi_\delta$ in the matrix has to be $\frac{\delta}{2}$ for reflection and matrix multiplication to give the same result, but how can I show/calculate it? Any hints are appreciated

Comment: At first, you treat $\delta$ like a vector, and then in the last paragraph you suggest it's a scalar. What do you mean?

Comment: you are right, $\delta$ is a vector. the angle would have to be $\frac{\pi}{2}$ then because it's a reflection, right?

Comment: I don't know what you mean. The matrix is a reflection *no matter what angle you put in,* so I don't know why one would conclude "reflection implies $\pi/2$."

Comment: I have to find a value for the angle $\varphi_\delta$ such that $$s_\delta (v) = \begin{pmatrix}v_1 \\ v_2 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}\cos(\varphi_\delta) & \sin(\varphi_\delta) \\ \sin(\varphi_\delta) & - \cos(\varphi_\delta)\end{pmatrix}$$ with $s_\delta$ of the form in my original post.

Comment: Yes: I hope you don't mind me writing $x$ in my own post for $\varphi_\delta$ just to save some complexity.

Comment: Thank you for your effort but I think your answer is too complicated/makes too little use of the definitions as this is just a small task. I think one has to find the value and do the calculation to verify it using the definitions.

Comment: Dear @sj134 : The value for $\varphi_\delta$ is $x$, given in my solution. That $\delta$ is an eigenvector for $-1$ of this transformation is a very elementary fact. I can't imagine a simpler connection between $\delta$ and your matrix, but by all means, if you find an easier solution let me know what you come up with. Regards

Answer (score 0):

Personally I think it is easiest to think about this in terms of eigenvectors. The reflection you're talking about has an eigenvalue of $-1$ in the direction of $\delta$ and an eigenvalue $1$ in the direction perpendicular to $\delta$.

So you're looking at this equation:

$\begin{bmatrix}\cos(x)&\sin(x)\\\sin(x)&-\cos(x)\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}\delta_1\\\delta_2\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}-\delta_1\\-\delta_2\end{bmatrix}$

This yields the equation $\delta_1\cos(x)+\delta_2\sin(x)=-\delta_1$, which is an equation in one unknown that we need to solve for $x$. Solving this results in $x=2\pi z -2\arctan(\frac{a}{b})$ for $z\in \Bbb Z$. Try to show this part.

The other equation resulting from the matrix multiplication, and the other two equations that come out of the computation looking for an eigenvector for $+1$ all turn out to be redundant with this single equation.

Comment: Technically $\delta_1 \cos \varphi + \delta_2 \sin \varphi = -\delta_1$ has one more family of solutions $\varphi \in \pi + 2\pi \mathbb Z$, which has to be ruled out by the other equation $\delta_1 \sin \varphi - \delta_2 \cos \varphi = -\delta_2$. And I think it would be better to clarify what $a$ and $b$ are.